# Customize ActionBar in android

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I need to show back button in actionbar on left hand side in my app

here is code that I use

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:icon="@drawable/back1"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>

</menu>
```

but using this option menu I get name of application and application icon on LHS and my back button on RHS
I want to remove application Icon from my activity and show only back button in actionbar

thanks!!!

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

or you can inflate your own layout in the place of the title

```
Button yourView = findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
ab.setCustomView(yourView));
```